# What symbol next? [Easy]

Tags: pattern

[image]

What's the next symbol?

Posted on: 2018/11/10

Comment: I think, it is ambiguous because some rules would need to be confirmed. If the sequence 8 items long, infinite or would eventually repeat itself.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

> A bar from top left to down right.

Because:

> The shapes are bar then circle of that bar, and the bar rotates 45° clockwise.

Comment: Makes sense. What about the colour?

Comment: But at the beginning, there are 3 vertical bars...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> a black vertical bar

Because

> The symbols come in pairs where the rightmost one is a circle plus the preceding symbol. It wraps around and starts over at the beginning when you get to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is

> A horizontal red bar.
> As the pattern stands, we have a bar, then a circle under that bar, then just the bar but angled (loosely) 45 degrees clockwise. However, the special positioning of the vertical and horizontal bars (orthogonal) causes them to first follow this pattern but once there is a horizontal bar with a circle, instead of rotating, the bar changes colour when it loses the circle then proceeds as usual.

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is:

> The visibility of the circle is alternating between visible and not visible.
>  **Thus it should be hidden for next symbol.** Also when the circle become visible, it has the previous symbol on it.

My second observation is:

> If we count changes (color, visibility or orientation) between symbols, we alternate between 2 changes and one change. For last symbol, there was a single change (adding a circle) so for next symbols, **there should be 2 changes.**

Third observation:

> When line change, it rotate 45% clockwise. So if it changes, it should be a . Possible pattern might be 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2... **Thus line would stay horizontal**.

Forth observation:

> Assuming that we have 2 colors. if it change, it would be red. Pattern seems to be 1, 2, 4, 8... **Thus color would be red**

Thus, I would say that the answer should be:

> A red horizontal line

However, at least one rule would be broken if we add one more symbol. Thus I think at least one extra hint would be necessary to decide which rule to keep.